# What exactly was Cook's plan and from whom did he get the money?

Tags: plot-explanation, drive

In the movie Drive, how did Cook plan to double cross the driver? And why didn't the pawn shop owner admit anything was stolen? And how did driver come to know from the news clip that he was setup?

Answer (score 5):

Cook planned to double-cross the Driver by pursuing him after the robbery (which he did), killing him (which he failed at), and taking the money.

Driver learns this from Christina Hendricks.

From IMDB:

> As Nino explains, the money belonged to an East coast mobster who was
>   moving it in to finance a new LA based operation. The pawn shop was a
>   front for him, and they would not want the police digging any deeper
>   into the crime than is necessary. Saying that there was only one
>   robber who ended up dead keeps them from tracing the money any
>   further.